# SQL: Select distinct children ordered by property of related child

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, sql-order-by, distinct

I've got a query where I want to retrieve distinct `child2` rows, but ordered by a property of `child1` rows that are related by a common parent. If I do the following, I get an error because the `ORDERBY` property is not in the `DISTINCT` list:

```
select 
    distinct c2.Id, c2.Foo, c2.Bar
    from Child1 c1
    join Parent p on c1.parentId = p.Id 
    join Child2 c2 on c2.parentId = p.Id
    order by c1.Id
```

However, if I add `c1.Id` to the select list, I will lose distinctness of `Child` rows, as `c1.Id` makes them all distinct.

If I use a CTE or subquery to first do the ordering, and then select distinct rows from that, the outer query doesn't guarantee that it will maintain the order of the inner/cte query.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you provde your table structure please?

Comment: So if you have two rows with same `c.foo` i `c.bar` and different `p.createdate`, which of two `createdate` do you want to use?

Comment: @Nenad there would be the child's primary key too, i'll add it to the example

Comment: @GoatInTheMachine If you truly have a parent/child relationship in there, why would there be a need for distinct? I have some parent/child relationships in my data, and there would be no need for a distinct clause. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Eli good point - I'm trying to make a simpler example, but I've made it too simple! I will fix it...

Comment: Sample data and expected output would be beneficial here.

Answer (score 3):

I make rows distinct in cte using `TOP(1) WITH TIES`, then sort in query

```
WITH Data AS(
    SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES 
        g.id, g.foo, g.bar, p.createdDate
    FROM Parent p
    JOIN Child c on c.parentId = p.id
    JOIN Grandchild g on g.childId = c.id
    ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY g.id, g.foo, g.bar ORDER BY p.createdDate)
)
SELECT * 
FROM Data
ORDER BY createdDate
```

`TOP(1) WITH TIES` selects rows where `ROW_NUMBER()..` = 1. Because of `PARTITION BY ...` it selects one row per partition(group). It works similar to `GROUP BY` but allows to return all columns

Comment: Won't the second 'outer' select from `Data` do it's own ordering though? I don't think it's guaranteed to maintain the ordering of the CTE?

Comment: I don't undestand your question. 'Outer' select is needed for sorting by `createdDate` only. CTE do not provide any sorting ( I use `order by` to `select distinct`)

Comment: I use following trick: `select top(1) with ties` + `order by row_number` = `select distinct` = `group by`

Comment: @MikhailLobanov What is the purpose of your `ORDER BY ROWNUMBER...` line within the CTE?

Answer (score 0):

Using Inline table:

```
  Select DISTINCT t.foo, t.bar From
  (SELECT
  c.foo, c.bar, p.createdDate
  FROM Parent p
  JOIN Child c on c.parentId = p.id
  )t
  ORDER BY t.createdDate
```